# What is the idiomatic way to start/stop a group of Upstarted services with a single command?

Tags: upstart

I have a set of a dozen or so services that usually are restarted in a group, but there are also cases where they need to be restarted / stopped individually.

It is cumbersome and error prone to have to issue Upstart commands for all 12 of them, but it seems like this has to be a somewhat common problem that upstart may have solved.

As of now, my solution is to do something like this:

```
find /etc/init -name "prefix*.conf" | while read i; do basename $i; done | cut -d "." -f1 | while read i; do sudo start $i; done
```

Comment: I can condense your command: `find /etc/init -name 'prefix*.conf' -exec basename -s .conf {} + | sudo xargs -L1 start`

Comment: As for controlling them as a group, I'd use [override files](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#override-files) that look for custom events and use `initctl emit`.